# smallest value of $k$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^na_i^3 \leq k \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^6}$?

Tags: inequality, arithmetic

**Question**: Let $n$ be an integer, $n \geq 3$. What is the smallest value of $k$ such that

$$\sum_{i=1}^na_i^3 \leq k \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^6} \;\; \text{ for all } a_i \in \mathbb{R}?$$

**My attempt so far:** It seems like we should be using Cauchy-Schwarz somehow...I note we are comparing the 1 norm and the 2 norm of the vector $(a_1^3, \dotsc a_n^3).$ How can we find some bounds for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, using Cauchy-Schwarz between $(a_1^3,\dots,a_n^3)$ and $(1,\dots,1)$, gives us that $$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^3\le \sqrt n\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^6}, $$ so the optimal $k$ must satisfy $k\le \sqrt n$.

What remains is to show that this is optimal. But if $a_i=1$ for all $i$, the left hand side is $n$, and the right hand side is $k\sqrt n$, so $k\ge \sqrt n$.

Comment: Thank you! The trick I had missed was to define the vector of all ones.